# Regular expression to match specific time related sentence

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds, regex-group, regex-negation

I'm trying to use a regular expression to match this sentence which repeats several times in large texts.

```
13 September 2020 14:24 Share
```

It can present with any day of the month, any month or year, any time but it always has the word Share at the end.

A text sample would look like this:

> Master your internal triggers by reassessing them.
>
> Start by changing the way you think about triggers. How? One way is to record them. Next time you feel yourself succumbing to distraction, grab a pen and some paper and write down what you are feeling and what triggered it. Maybe it was a sudden wave of anxiety; maybe it was that your boss made you angry. Note down when it occurred and how you felt once you noticed the trigger.
>
> 9 February, 2021 15:12 Share
>
> If you do this regularly, you will learn to identify triggers. Once you’ve got the hang of it, you can begin letting go of them. Psychologist Jonathan Bricker suggests a simple visualization technique: imagine sitting next to a stream and watching your distracting thoughts being carried away on leaves floating on the water.
>
> 9 February, 2021 15:12 Share
>
> Here’s another tip: make your tasks more fun.
>
> 9 February, 2021 15:14 Share

---

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `\b\d{1,2} (?:January|February|March|...),? \d{4} \d{1,2}:\d{2} Share\b`.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```js
\d+\s+\w+,\s*\d{4} \d{1,2}:\d{2} Share
```

See [regex proof](https://regex101.com/r/oiQQKt/1).

**EXPLANATION**

```js
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \d+                      digits (0-9) (1 or more times (matching
                           the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \s+                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (1 or
                           more times (matching the most amount
                           possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \w+                      word characters (a-z, A-Z, 0-9, _) (1 or
                           more times (matching the most amount
                           possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ,                        ','
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \s*                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (0 or
                           more times (matching the most amount
                           possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \d{4}                    digits (0-9) (4 times)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                           ' '
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \d{1,2}                  digits (0-9) (between 1 and 2 times
                           (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  :                        ':'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \d{2}                    digits (0-9) (2 times)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   Share                   ' Share'
```

Comment: I would at least use word boundaries and use `\d{1,2}` instead of `\d+`.